# Easy way to add 'copy to clipboard' to GitHub markdown?

Tags: github, markdown

Specifically, I have blocks of code for install that I want the user to be able to quickly copy and paste into a terminal. I'd like a button to 'copy to clipboard' for the code block. Since there's a 'copy to clipboard' button for the git clone URLs, I was wondering if I could piggy back off that or if not whether there was some relatively simple I could add to the MD to make this happen. Or is this simply not possible with the processing and 'safication' the MD text goes through?

Comment: it is simply not possible.

Comment: Or at least, not without requesting a new feature, I presume.

Comment: I believe the  'copy to clipboard' button for the git clone URLs uses Flash under the hood to write to the clipboard (as the browser does not provide write access to the clipboard via JavaScript). I expect it would be pretty difficult, if not impossible, to piggyback on that, even using some sort of browser extension/scripting plugin.

Comment: @Waylan not anymore it doesn;t :)

Comment: @bitoiu that is great news!

Comment: There is an extension for that: https://github.com/panzerdp/clipboardy

Comment: It is possible now (May 2021). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67478530/6309)

Comment: @toddmo the first 6 comments are outdated, this was not possible in 2015, it seems possible since a UI refresh a few years ago. I've upvoted the comment from vonc. I don't think the platform strives to go around deleting comments, thus the dates next to them, and overtime the voting system will correct that organically.

Comment: @bitoiu, the reason why I said delete it isn't because it's outdated. Sorry I wasn't more to the point. It's making some people give up when there actually is a solution now, because it's positioned at the very top of the reading flow. It's not helping anything by being there. But it is doing some harm every now and then.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The copy button is now a reality (May 2021), as [tweeted by Nat Friedman](https://twitter.com/natfriedman/status/1391862005095485440)

> We just added a "Copy" button to all code blocks on GitHub.
>
> [image: Copy]

To create a copy button, make a [Fenced code block](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks) as shown here, in a markdown document

````
```
function test() {
  console.log("This code will have a copy button to the right of it");
}
```
````

Comment: Does this apply to gists? I don't see the copy option in my gists.

Comment: @magician11 not yet, I believe. (or at least, [not consistently](https://twitter.com/polm23/status/1432917660258340877)).

Comment: can you add how to add a code block in markdown please

Comment: I don't see any copy buttons in any of my codeblocks in github...

Comment: @Jim I see them in the markdown `README` of [`HenrikBengtsson/future`](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future), for instance, by moving the mouse in the top right corner of any code block.

Answer (score 6):

I think that it is not what you want, but if you want to copy, you can do it by running the bookmarklet and adding a copy button.

```
var copy = function(target) {
    var textArea = document.createElement('textarea')
    textArea.setAttribute('style','width:1px;border:0;opacity:0;')
    document.body.appendChild(textArea)
    textArea.value = target.innerHTML
    textArea.select()
    document.execCommand('copy')
    document.body.removeChild(textArea)
}

var pres = document.querySelectorAll(".comment-body > pre")
pres.forEach(function(pre){
  var button = document.createElement("button")
  button.className = "btn btn-sm"
  button.innerHTML = "copy"
  pre.parentNode.insertBefore(button, pre)
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    copy(pre.childNodes[0])
  })
})
```

Comment: Hmm, I'll check it out.

Comment: I couldn't get this working in Chrome. I didn't do a lot of debugging, but I thought I saw something about a limitation or bug on the Chrome bookmarklets. I love the idea, though.

Comment: You probably need to surround this with a `window.onload = function() {` if you are running it off a script on a webpage

Answer (score 1):

##### This is probably the most straightforward way I know of.

So all you have to do is Any Header/subtitle or any text you want starting with hash, then in the next line, you add your copyable text like below,

**[Hash Sign(#)][Space]Any Header/subtitle or any text you want starting with hash

[Tab][Tab]Your text**

This should look like this.

**Example 1:**

##### To create a copyable code block, create a Header like this. Then put two tab gaps

```
YourCopyableTextblock
```

**Example 2:**

###### To create a copyable code block, create a comment like this. Then put two tab gaps

```
YourCopyableTextblock
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use any markdown header (one or more #), then enter(line change) and two tabs. Visuals added below:

```
##
<tab><tab>code/text here
```

And you are done :).

Below is screenshot from my one of project -

To get below:
[image]

I used below :
[image: Readme screenshot]

Here is link to my project if you want to check out - https://github.com/tukeshwar/automation-with-chatgpt/edit/master/README.md

By the way, above project is meant to help to write better with AI for free :).

Bonus tip : If you don't want the line above, use smaller header like "######"