# Add a copy to clipboard button in a GitHub readme

Tags: github

I am writing a README.md in GitHub Flavored Markdown, which I'll push on a GitHub repository. Is there any way to add a copy-to-clipboard button for each code snippet the README.md contains, when viewing on `https://github.com/username/reponame/README.me`?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908564/easy-way-to-add-copy-to-clipboard-to-github-markdown)

Comment: There is an extension for that: https://github.com/panzerdp/clipboardy

Answer (score 5):

Since 5 years later I was Googling the same in question... here is  another Chrome extension to copy the posted source code from readme files: [codecopy](https://github.com/zenorocha/codecopy#install)

> It works on:
>
> - [GitHub](https://github.com/)
> - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/)
> - [Gist](https://gist.github.com/)
> - [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)
> - [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites)
> - [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)
> - [Medium](https://medium.com/)
>
> [And more](https://github.com/zenorocha/codecopy/blob/7c638611f7ad01d923361f7fedfe3933b35e114c/dist/manifest.json#L27).

Obviously ideally it'd be great not to have to install any extension.

Comment: GitHub supports this by default. Check out Readme of my one of project where I used this formatting style -
 https://github.com/tukeshwar/automation-with-chatgpt/edit/master/README.md
Try editing to see the markdown code used.

Answer (score 3):

I created a Chrome extension to copy the posted source code from readme files.
It works on:

- github
- stackoverflow
- npmjs

Check the repository: https://github.com/panzerdp/clipboardy

Answer (score 0):

It is easy on Github, just use the code block generation and specify the language
[ex for terminal command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyPEU.png)

```bash
git init
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8p6i.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use any markdown header (one or more #), then enter(line change) and two tabs. Visuals added below:

```
##
<tab><tab>code/text here
```

And you are done :).

Below is screenshot from my one of project -

To get below:
[image]

I used below :
[image: Readme screenshot]

Here is link to my project if you want to check out - https://github.com/tukeshwar/automation-with-chatgpt/edit/master/README.md

By the way, above project is meant to help to write better with AI for free :).

Bonus tip : If you don't want the line above, use smaller header like "######"